# How do I get nested esi tags working?

Tags: php, symfony, varnish, esi

I am using ESI with Symfony and Varnish. 
What I am trying to do is..

Render an `esi` block, inside another `esi` block.

Unfortunately the nested `esi` tags are not replaced.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please post some code for more clarity

Comment: Fragment revised for more clarity